# Android : How to read log

Tags: android, logging

I didn't find a way to read log of my android app. Logcat and other apps are just show the logs at that moment. But when my app crash i should be able to read it . I also try *#9900# . It shows some options to copy log , but the location android said i saved is empty.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You copy that log which you find after *#9900# and paste it into a text file. And in Redmi devices we have option to read crash log too.

Comment: When SysDump menu open . for example when i push the 
 RUN DUMOSTATE/LOGCAT/MODEM LOG
1 dialog appears
Dump Result
  Saved Location : 
      /data/log/dumpState.........log  it says. But there isnt any directory name log in data folder . I tried to find via computer or filemanager. Both not find anything.

Comment: /data folder can only be accessed if your phone is rooted otherwise not, you have rely on exception handling to know why app crashed

Comment: You will see data folder in non rooted phones but empty.

Comment: Root your phone then.

Comment: No it's not the efficient way to solve this problem. I will try to read log programmaticaly and save them.

Comment: That's what I said earlier to take help of stack traces

Comment: i rooted my phone. But still i cannot find any log folder yet.